# EhCache 2.10.x is very heavy

Tags: maven, ehcache, hibernate-cache

Using Maven, I updated our Hibernate version to 5.x and it comes now transitive with EhCache 2.10.x. This version is very heavy ([about 10 Mb](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.10.6)). This is annoying in a small application. The JAR includes lot of .class files from J2EE, like `javax.servlet`. Is there somewhere a slim EhCache 2.10.x version of the JAR? Or how could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you see only `ehcache` I can only see a single transitive dependency which is `slf4j`....

```
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
```

but what I can see is that inside the ehcache jar file all those mentioned classes are included which is really bad...I would file in a ticket at the ehcache project...

Comment: I believe you are unfortunately right. I also searched for an alternative JAR (without dependencies included) and I couldn't find any. Maybe I would have to package my own version of ehcache JAR, if I want to avoid those included dependencies.